# finding the user who deleted the record

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

I have a PL/SQL audit trigger which logs all the changes done to a table.

I am able to find the user_id which inserted/deleted the record. (The user_id comes from a web application, the code for which I don't have access as of now).

so,

```
TRIGGER AUD_CONFIG_TRG
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON CONFIG   
IF INSERTING OR UPDATING THEN
v_user_value_txt := :NEW.AUDIT_UPDATED_USER_ID;
```

However, for delete, I can't simply use the OLD.AUDIT_UPDATED_USER_ID, and I can't use the new either, since the new record won't be accessible.

I thought about using BEFORE DELETE, but still I can only get an older userid and not the one who deleted this record.

How do I go about if I want to change the rigger such that it can maintain an audit of who deleted the record? Is there someway I can pass this through the code?

Comment: +1 great question - we had the same issue recently. We solved it by revoking DELETE privilege from all tables where this was a problem; and adding a "soft delete" function - i.e. add a "deleted" flag to the table, turning the user's "delete" action into a simple update of a flag.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could use the UID function, as in:

```
CREATE TRIGGER AUD_CONFIG_TRG
  AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON CONFIG
  REFERENCING NEW AS NEW
              OLD AS OLD
  FOR EACH ROW
  DECLARE
    V_USER_VALUE_TXT  VARCHAR2(32);
  BEGIN
    IF INSERTING OR UPDATING THEN
      V_USER_VALUE_TXT := :NEW.AUDIT_UPDATED_USER_ID;
    END IF;

    IF DELETING THEN
      V_USER_VALUE_TXT := UID;
    END IF;
  END AUD_CONFIG_TRG;
```

If you want the user name instead of the ID number you can use the USER function instead of UID.

Share and enjoy.

Comment: yes, I guess that is the only option I have. I am trying to get the OS username so that it is a better indicator of who is doing the change.